# How to create a value channel of files?

Tags: nextflow

How do I add file inputs to many parallel processes?

I want to do something like this:

```
proteins = Channel.fromPath( '/some/path/*.fa' )
executions = Channel.from(1, 2, 3, 4)

process blastThemAll {
  input:
  val num from executions
  file query_file from proteins

  "blastp -query ${query_file} -db nr"

}
```

I want to have 4 processes that each will have access to all the files in the proteins channel. Basically, I want the proteins channel to be a value channel that contains a list of files.

I couldn't find how to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [collect](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#operator-collect) operator,  which collects all the items emitted by a channel to a List and return the resulting object as a sole emission.

> A [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel) is created using the [value](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value) factory method or by
> operators returning a single value, such us [first](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#operator-first), [last](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#operator-last), [collect](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#operator-collect),
> [count](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#operator-count), [min](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#operator-min), [max](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#operator-max), [reduce](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#operator-reduce), [sum](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#operator-sum).

For example:

```
proteins = Channel.fromPath( '/some/path/*.fa' ).collect()
executions = Channel.from(1, 2, 3, 4)

process blastThemAll {

  tag { "job ${num}" }

  input:
  val num from executions
  path query_file from proteins

  """
  find . -name '*.fa'
  """
}
```

And run with:

```
nextflow run -ansi-log false test.nf
```

Results:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `test.nf` [gloomy_mclean] - revision: 53ee46a154
[c9/6da993] Submitted process > blastThemAll (job 4)
[0e/24cc9b] Submitted process > blastThemAll (job 1)
[43/c500eb] Submitted process > blastThemAll (job 2)
[6b/d75ce4] Submitted process > blastThemAll (job 3)
```

Comment: I missed that Note in the docs about the operators creating a value channel. thanks!